# not able to set icon using style component, however same style is working perfectly fine in ".css" file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

this is styled component i am using and in HTML i am not able see my icon how ever same thing working in .css file

```
// CSS
.name {
    width: 70%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("../../Icons/icons8-male-user-24.png");
    background-position: 2% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

// js
export const Username = styled.input`
    width: 70%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-image: url("../../Icons/icons8-male-user-24.png");
    background-position: 2% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: none;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
`;
```

Comment: If rendered via a browser switch on your browser dev tools and get some more insight into what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you resolve the path.

> This tells webpack to include that file in the bundle. Unlike CSS imports, importing a file gives you a string value. This value is the final path you can reference in your code.

```
import path from "../../Icons/icons8-male-user-24.png";

export const Username = styled.input`
  background-image: url(${path});
`;
```

See [Adding Images Fonts and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files).